# Create Product Finder Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, catalog, catalogsearch

I want to create product finder page same as listing of products in catalog page.
Here I have product listing page: [image]
In this page I have filter and products as per chosen category.

Now I want the page like here: [image]

So I think I have to create duplicate listing page of catalog module and put only simple page where all sidebar data will display without any products.

Please suggest how to create Product Finder Page?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one [Module](https://github.com/ergopalpatel/Custom-Product-List)

On **landing page** it will show **entire collection** of your store then you **can filter it like normal product list**.

In `Hpl_Productlist_Model_Layer` **protected function _getCollection()**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
return $collection;
```

You can set **URL Key** in `Hpl_Productlist_Controller_Router`

```
const NEW_PRODUCTS_URL_KEY = '<YOUR URL KEY>';
```

update **controller**

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        if(count($this->getRequest()->getParams()) >0)
        {
            $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
             $xml = "<reference name='content'><remove name='new_products_container'><block type='core/template' name='finder.page' template='finder/page.phtml'/></reference>";
            $update->addUpdate($xml);
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

create template `finder/page.phtml`

Comment: Will it display all products when I land on URL page?

Comment: @JackPirates Yes. On url page it will load your entire product list. check `__getCollection()` function

Comment: I think you didn't getting my question. You are correct but what I want is the second page you can see in screenshot without any product when land on page.

Comment: @JackPirates you can display none that on landing page. and after selection on any filter it will work as per your requirement . You have to do some customization like `if there is no parameter then set your template in content block`

Comment: If I create one new category and add all the products in new category then put one condition in list.phtml (`<?php if(strpos($currentUrl,'product-finder.html') == false): ?>`) then display all products and if TRUE then not display any products.
Can I do this way?

Comment: Yes you can @JackPirates but for that each time you have to assign products to that category also

Comment: @JackPirates find updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54169/discussion-between-jack-pirates-and-gopal-patel).